# Adding data to mysql with servlet not working

Tags: java, mysql, servlets

This is my database

```
CREATE TABLE `Animal` ( `name` varchar(128) NOT NULL, `breed` varchar(128) NOT NULL, `age` varchar(128) NOT NULL )
```

register.html to fill in the data

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="servlet/Register" method="post">

name <input type="text" name="name"/><br/><br/>
breed <input type="password" name="breed"/><br/><br/>
age <input type="password" name="age"/><br/><br/>
<br/><br/>
<input type="submit" value="register"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

My servlet

```
package animals;


import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class Register extends HttpServlet {

public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    String name = request.getParameter("name");
    String breed = request.getParameter("breed");
    String age = request.getParameter("age");


    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test", "root", "");
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(
                "INSERT INTO Animal (name,breed,age) VALUES(?,?,?)");

        ps.setString(1, name);
        ps.setString(2, breed);
        ps.setString(3, age);


        int i = ps.executeUpdate();
        if (i > 0) {
            out.print("Data successfully registered...");
        }

    } catch (Exception e2) {
        System.out.println(e2);
    }

    out.close();
}

}
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee       http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Register</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>animals.Register</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Register</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/servlet/Register</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>register.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

When I fill in the form and submit, it send me to /register but it's blank and it doesn't add data in my database.

I'm 100% sure that my connection to the java database is working, because I have another project with a login with the same connection to the database and that one is working.

Any tips / comments are welcome

Comment: So what diagnostics have you performed? Are you sure the request is getting through to your servlet? Have you logged anything? Is your driver set to auto-commit? (If not, maybe that's the problem.)

Comment: Are you getting any error in Console?

Comment: I'm guessing it's @JonSkeet 's suggestion for the auto-commit.

Comment: @Dilip No errors in the console

Comment: What do you mean with auto-commit? @JonSkeet

Comment: You should have good logging in your code. Helps you understand issues quickly. Try printing values in the `doPost()` method to confirm values are actually coming to your servlet.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but I think in JDBC drivers autocommit is set to true by default ([docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html)).

Comment: Try debug your Servlet, put breakpoints on your request.getParameter() methods, if the values are coming, then the problem is with your DB or its connection, if the values are not coming then problem is outside of Servlet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few things you can check :
1. Debug the code & check if values are captured by the servlet.
2. Use commit() after the executeUpdate(). Maybe your config is set to auto-commit off due to some reasons.
3. Is this string printed? "Data successfully registered..."
4. Lastly, Any exceptions?